# SSRS matrix report total sum from expression

Tags: reporting-services, matrix, sum, expression

I am trying to create sum() expression which will summarize rows and place results into "Total Servers in TPM" column. Looks like I am not able to provide the right feed for sum expression.

SSRS matrix report in design mode looks like:

[Matrix report picture](http://img812.imageshack.us/img812/2866/matrix1c.jpg)

[TPM_scan_type] expression can have 2 values: 
"TPM Succesfull Scan" or 
"TPM Failed Scan"

```
=Switch(Fields!ScanStatus.Value = "OK","TPM Succesfull Scan",Fields!ScanStatus.Value = "FAILED!","TPM Failed Scan")
```

[scan_count] expression just aggregate values for each "Primary SA"

```
=Switch(Fields!ScanStatus.Value="FAILED!",Count(Fields!ScanStatus.Value),Fields!ScanStatus.Value="OK", CountDistinct(Fields!ServerName.Value))
```

Results:

[Report output picture](http://img90.imageshack.us/img90/4820/matrix2c.jpg)

Data sample:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TPM_test') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.TPM_test;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.TPM_test
(
ServerName   varchar(30) NOT NULL,
ScanStatus   varchar(10) NOT NULL,
Primary_SA   varchar(30) NOT NULL,
HotfixID     int
);

INSERT INTO dbo.TPM_test(ServerName, ScanStatus, Primary_SA, HotfixID)
VALUES('LDNSQLF700', 'OK', 'SA1', 157848);
INSERT INTO dbo.TPM_test(ServerName, ScanStatus, Primary_SA, HotfixID)
VALUES('LDNSQLF700', 'OK', 'SA1', 976832);
INSERT INTO dbo.TPM_test(ServerName, ScanStatus, Primary_SA, HotfixID)
VALUES('LDNSQLF700', 'OK', 'SA1', 234354);
INSERT INTO dbo.TPM_test(ServerName, ScanStatus, Primary_SA, HotfixID)
VALUES('NYSQL502', 'FAILED!', 'SA1', '');
INSERT INTO dbo.TPM_test(ServerName, ScanStatus, Primary_SA, HotfixID)
VALUES('PSQL1011', 'FAILED!', 'SA1', '');
INSERT INTO dbo.TPM_test(ServerName, ScanStatus, Primary_SA, HotfixID)
VALUES('NTQDF002', 'OK', 'SA1', 878641);

INSERT INTO dbo.TPM_test(ServerName, ScanStatus, Primary_SA, HotfixID)
VALUES('AUSSQL140', 'OK', 'SA2', 537990);
INSERT INTO dbo.TPM_test(ServerName, ScanStatus, Primary_SA, HotfixID)
VALUES('AUSSQL140', 'OK', 'SA2', 1349605);
INSERT INTO dbo.TPM_test(ServerName, ScanStatus, Primary_SA, HotfixID)
VALUES('JAP543X2', 'FAILED!', 'SA2', '');
INSERT INTO dbo.TPM_test(ServerName, ScanStatus, Primary_SA, HotfixID)
VALUES('EU456CLX', 'FAILED!', 'SA2', '');
INSERT INTO dbo.TPM_test(ServerName, ScanStatus, Primary_SA, HotfixID)
VALUES('EUCTX654', 'OK', 'SA2', 5637965);
INSERT INTO dbo.TPM_test(ServerName, ScanStatus, Primary_SA, HotfixID)
VALUES('EUCTX654', 'OK', 'SA2', 6464367) ;
INSERT INTO dbo.TPM_test(ServerName, ScanStatus, Primary_SA, HotfixID)
VALUES('EUCTX654', 'OK', 'SA2', 1323123) ;
INSERT INTO dbo.TPM_test(ServerName, ScanStatus, Primary_SA, HotfixID)
VALUES('EUCTX654', 'OK', 'SA2', 1004326) ;
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't be easier to just use the `CountRows` function instead of a `Switch` statement for **scan_count**?

It looks like you're already got row/column groups set up in your Matrix, so `CountRows` will just be executed in whatever Scope it's called and give your desired result.

I created a simple test DataSet:

[image]

With this DataSet I added a calculated field **TPM_scan_type** based on your expression above.

Based on this I created a standard Matrix:

[image]

In each case the expression in the screenshot is just `=CountRows()`.

Also note that **Total Servers in TPM** is outside of the column group scope.

End result:

[image]

This looks like what you require and seems to do it in a simpler way.

**Edit after comment:**

OK, I've changed the DataSet to include duplicate rows for *OK* **ScanStatus** results:

[image]

I've changed the **Total Servers in TPM** expression to the following:

```
=Count(IIf(Fields!ScanStatus.Value = "FAILED!", Fields!ServerName.Value, Nothing))
    + CountDistinct(IIf(Fields!ScanStatus.Value = "OK", Fields!ServerName.Value, Nothing))
```

Which gives the required results, I think, the same as the above report output with this new DataSet.

In fact, this can also be used for **TPM_Scan_Type**, too.

One last suggestion - is there any reason you can't just use `=CountDistinct(Fields!ServerName.Value)` for all expressions? If I understand your data this will give the required results - it works for the above DataSet, for example.

**Edit after Dataset added:**

I have updated the report to use your sample data:

[image]

Result for both expressions, i.e.

```
=Count(IIf(Fields!ScanStatus.Value = "FAILED!", Fields!ServerName.Value, Nothing))
    + CountDistinct(IIf(Fields!ScanStatus.Value = "OK", Fields!ServerName.Value, Nothing))
```

and

```
=CountDistinct(Fields!ServerName.Value)
```

[image]

So to me it seems you can use `=CountDistinct(Fields!ServerName.Value)` in all cases.

Comment: Can you add a sample Dataset of half a dozen rows if mine is not useful for the example? Also, can you explain why you use `Count(Fields!ScanStatus.Value)` for failure and `CountDistinct(Fields!ServerName.Value)` for success?

Comment: Hi @Ian. Thanks for the quick answer. CountRows() can partially do the job however the dataset I have, forced me to use switch. It's all because Fields!ScanStatus can have two values for a server:   "FAILED!" or "OK". But "FAILED!" is unique value (for each machine), opposite to "OK!" which is repeated few times for each server (as scan returns missing hotfixes on the server). So I need to distinct "OK" values to get count of servers where scan was successful.

Comment: I placed data sample as SQL table above. Regarding question you previous asked: "can you explain why you use ...CountDistinct(Fields!ServerName.Value) for success?" Failure has unique values so I just count them by "Count(Fields!ScanStatus.Value)". I can't aggregate by "OK" status as I only get ones in each row so I use serverName instead which do the job.

Comment: OK, I analyzed your code and It works great. Thank you @Ian. And yes, I can also use "=CountDistinct(Fields!ServerName.Value)"